# jquery detect more keys entered in background with return as last key?

Tags: jquery, keystore

I feel bit lost with keyboard events.

I want to detect last 10 characters entered with return as the last character.

Have any idea how to implement it? I'm not asking for code but rather for logic and guidelines.

Comment: `I feel bit lost with keyboard events.` I suppose you could start with the jQuery API documentation on [**keyboard events**](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/) Those demos should hopefully help you explain things. Also have a look at the [**keyup event examples**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing you are using jQuery you can bind to the `keyup` event and then store the data in an array as you type, similar to this:

```
<input id="myText"></input>
```

```
var textString = [];

$('#myText').on('keyup', function(eventData){
    if(eventData.which === 13){ // check if enter/return was pressed
        // It wasn't clear what you wanted to happen exactly on enter, 
        // so as an example the code simply alerts the last 10 chars.
        alert('Enter was pressed. Your last 10 chars were: ' + textString.join(''));
        return;
    }

    textString.push(this.value.slice(-1)); // store last character type in the array

    // if adding the last entry increased the array passed the 10 characters
    // remove the one from the beginning of the array
    if(textString.length > 10){
        textString.shift();
    }
})
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/nm4TV/) - Binding the `keup` event and storing last 10 characters

---

As you are asking for jQuery, the code above is using jQuery's [**on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for binding to the [**keyup**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event of the specified input element.

Once inside the event the code is using JavaScript's [**Array.push()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add the new element to the end of the array and JavaScript's [**Array.shift()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) to remove the first element in the array.

For obtaining the last typed character the code is using JavaScript's [**String.slice()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) which extracts a specific section of a string.

To display the array's values as a string in the alert the code is using JavaScript's [**Array.join()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Make an array and store all events in it, removing the front element when the length is > 10, and use that array when you get "return" as input.

Pseudocode:

```
var events = [];
function keypress(e) {
  if(e == "return") {
    console.log(events);
  }
  events.push(e);
  if(events.length > 10) {
    events.shift();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to match the button you press with keycode, ie:

```
var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
}
```

With this code if someone press "enter" you can do something.

Check this to know all the possible keycodes: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Hope it help.

Comment: As OP is using jQuery there is no need for the check on `e.keyCode` and so on. That is because jQuery normalizes the `.which` property so you can **reliably** use it to retrieve the key code.